# Why does the Lamb-Dicke parameter decrease with the number of ions in an ion chain

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-optics, quantum-computer, decoherence, ion-traps

I would like to understand (ideally with a nice pedagogic reference), why the fidelity of quantum gates in long ion chain decreases with the number of ions in the chain.

In [this reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.04178), it is explained on page 27 that it is because the Lamb-Dicke parameter decreases with the total number of ions in the chain. This parameter is proportional to the gate speed, hence it makes gates slower when more and more ions are in the chain. Because they are slower they become noisier (more errors have the time to occur). In the reference I provided, there are reference to other papers which says that the decay law is $1/\sqrt{N}$, $N$ being the number of ions in the trap, but there is no explanation for why it is the case: why does the lamb-Dicke parameter decrease with the number of ions in the chain?

I am looking for such an explanation. An ideal answer would, in addition of an explanation, provide a link with a pedagogic reference explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a chain of $N$ singly charged ions, each with mass $m$.
The Lamb-Dicke parameter $\eta_{ip}$ for exciting an ion $i$ of mass $m$ with mode $p$ with laser is given by $\eta_{ip}=\vec{k}\cdot\vec{e}_p b_{ip}\xi_p$, where $\vec{k}\cdot\vec{e}_p$ is the wave vector overlap with the motion direction, $b_{ip}$ is the participation of the ion $i$ in mod $p$, and $\xi_p=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega_p}}$ is the zero-point spread of the harmonic oscillator. [Debnath's PhD Thesis](https://iontrap.umd.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Shantanu_Debnath_ThesisV1.pdf)

If the laser driving the motion has a total overlap with the mode, then $\vec{k}\cdot\vec{e}_p=\vert \vec{k}\vert=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$, where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the laser. Then the Lamb-Dicke parameter is $\eta_{ip}=b_{ip}\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega_p}}$.
If you consider the in-phase or so-called center-of-mass motion, $p=1$, where all the ions participate equally, then $\omega_1$ is the trap strength, independent of $N$, and $b_{ip}=\frac1{\sqrt{N}}$. This gives the $\sqrt{N}$ dependence of the Lamb-Dicke parameter [Quantum dynamics of cold trapped ions, with application to quantum computation](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9702053).